# How to change content url content/title to text/title?

Tags: path-aliases

I created some content and changed the URL `content/title` to `text/title`.
My issue is why my changes didn't apply on some content.

Answer (score 3):

You probably have to delete and then bulk create them from the `admin/config/search/path/delete_bulk` and `admin/config/search/path/update_bulk` pages.

Be careful though if there are links pointing towards pages.

Comment: Also,be sure to clear the drupal cache.

Comment: Quick note about this solution: Do this during low visiting times, and in maintenance mode. Depending on how much content you have, it may take a while. If you're not in maintenance mode, you may end up with conflicts due to the script changing paths while others edit the same content at the same time.